# How to use two Jenkins build jobs for three environments?

Tags: javascript, jenkins, gulp

I have 2 build jobs, one to dev and one to stage and 3 deploy jobs (dev, stage, prod). The stage build job adds the build to Artifactory which the prod deploy fetches file from, so I don´t want a build job for prod. I use Gulp for building (for now) with a task for reading NODE_ENV and selecting the correct env config. I´ve got 3 env js config files (dev, stage, prod) in the repo.

So I want to be able to set 3 x environment variables in only 2 build jobs. One option might be to create two html files in the gulp compile/stage build job, eg. index_stage.html and index_prod.html, with the different env file included, and then rename one .html and remove the other in the corresponding deploy job. But that seems a bit hacky, any other suggestions?